# Calculate Overtime Based On StartTime And StopTime

Tags: ms-access

I have a table where I register the duration of events that take place in an Auditorium of the company I work in. The table has all the event data includind the TimeStart field and TimeEnd field.

Our technician shift ends at 6pm.

So if an event duration ends beyond 6pm, I need to track the overtime the technician worked.

Can anyone help me with this matter?

Thanks to everyone in advance,
Hope your all safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be:

```vb
ShiftEnd = #06:00:00 PM#
Overtime = CDate(DurationEnd - ShiftEnd)
```

If over-Midnight may be expected, as one day:

```vb
Overtime = TimeValue(CDate(1 + DurationEnd - ShiftEnd))
```

The "magic" here is due to the nature of data type Date around numeric zero:

[MS Access Can Handle Millisecond Time Values--Really : Page 2](https://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046/0/page/2)

Notice the graph: [Firgure 1](https://www.devx.com/supportitems/showSupportItem.php?co=39046&supportitem=figure1).

Overtime will be counted in days. To obtain an hour value, multiply by 24.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav. :) It works, but not as expected. If an event actually ends after 06pm, say 06:30pm, It really does return 00.30.00. But if an event ends at  04pm, it returns 02:00:00. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, see extended answer, please.

Comment: I see, that is to be considered if the duration of the event goes beyond midnight. Nice! However, i'm still facing the same problem. If the event ends before the ShiftEnd value, it returns whatever value is needed to reach de 06:00. I was intended to have it only showing a value if the DurationEnd was greater than the ShiftEnd value.